# Abraham Lincoln and Meryl Streep, are they the same?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570097/what-is-another-word-for-historical-figure) about naming Abraham Lincoln something other than ***historical figure*** was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218770/meryl-streep-is-a-as-a-big-compliment) which tries to find a compliment for Meryl Streep (!), but I honestly do not see how the answers of the second can apply to the first. The tags of the question include ***history*** and ***terminology***, so I doubt the OP is looking for a metaphor.

But maybe I am missing something, so I just post this here in case someone can enlighten me.

Comment: It's a very low quality question. There are just two sentences, it lacks effort and it's devoid of research, so for this site it is too simple and basic. All the OP had to do was look in a good dictionary.

Comment: The question was closed for lack of research, it was not closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don’t understand why close reasons are hidden now. It seems like it is intended to reset community standards by keeping newer users in the dark about what the “veteran” users think is appropriate handling so they don’t learn “bad” habits by the time they earn the privilege to close vote. All it does is sow confusion though.

Comment: The first user voted to close because it was a duplicate. The others followed. I agree the question needs details and clarity. But it is definitely NOT a duplicate. So we will leave it at that.

Comment: @colleen, we would need to edit the close reasons so that something reasonable is shown to each user. See for example this mse question about their own close reason: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367025/lets-update-our-only-applicable-to-one-specific-site-close-reason-to-utilize

Comment: Your post says the OP was closed as a duplicate. It wasn't. Two users VTC  because it lacked research. And it's difficult to fault that logic.

Answer (score 4):

Mari-lou A has indicated in the comments that the question was closed because it lacked research. You seem to be assuming that it was closed as a duplicate because it has a "Does this answer your question?..." but if the post notice doesn't actually say:

> This question already has answers here:

it wasn't closed as a duplicate (Even the really old questions that don't show which questions they are a duplicate of have that text). Unfortunately, if it was closed for one of the ELU custom reasons, the post notice isn't very informative.

As stated in [an answer to New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339733/273494):

> Unfortunately, with the new post notices, questions closed with custom close reasons now simply say they were closed as off-topic. There’s no explanation of why they're off-topic, and in many cases the questions are about subjects that are entirely topical for the site.

As Laurel pointed out in the comments, if ELU would like more informative close reasons displayed, [we would need to come up with the appropriate text for each type of post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/273494).

Comment: I am 100% on board with coming up with appropriate text for each type of post notice. The limits on the custom close reasons felt unreasonably retroactive and left many OPs like they’d been left out to dry.

Comment: @CollenV Thank you, I honestly thought it was closed as a duplicate first because at that comment. I realised after posting my question here, that there was no duplicate indicated, and so that the question was not closed for that reason. I do agree with you and Mary-LouA that it is a question poorly expressed and that it was rightfully closed. But it was too late to delete my question here, as there was very interesting information  about the new post notices.

Comment: @fev Asking on meta was the right thing to do. If you hadn’t asked I wouldn’t have learned about the custom close reasons. There was probably at least one other person that looked at that question and had the same concerns but didn’t bother to ask about it.

Comment: While it is true that its being a duplicate was not **the** reason for closing, it still was **a** reason: the question was closed because two people regarded it as lacking research and one person regarded it as a duplicate. One of the problems with the banners presenting 'reasons' for closing (in addition to their being poorly worded) is that they are designed to give only one reason, selected by some algorithm, while in reality there is often a multiplicity of reasons (which are sometimes not even compatible with each other).

Comment: @jsw29 [Two reasons are shown in the close notice if two voters (or a moderator) chose one community-specific canned reason, and 2-3 other voters chose a different one.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351263/273494). Whether that's implemented correctly for a 3-vote closure I don't know, but the post notices do handle multiple reasons when there isn't a consensus. I think there should be a choice to "close" posts that can't be saved or put them "on hold". If you choose "hold", you get to tick as many items as you like on a list of canned advice for improving the post or enter free-form text.

Comment: I think forcing people to choose one reason as the main form of feedback for people to improve their post is a bad design. I shouldn't have to provide a reason for extremely low quality unsalvageable posts. For posts that can be improved, it would be nice to be able to be able to customize advice for fixing the problems without having to write a full blown comment with links to the help center and such. Usually posts that get closed have more than one issue.

Comment: @jsw29 In the second comment to this answer, I have already explained what actually happened. I am far from criticising the closing of the question. I just wanted to state that I did not think it was a duplicate. And then this interesting issue of the post notices appeared, so although my question here is far from "astonishing", I am happy it helped me learn something new. Sorry if I annoyed anyone by bringing this up.